# API for searching vehicles to get their characteristics and images

Tags: api

I want to make an application in which users can search for cars and have all the information on the car they are looking for, these different characteristics and one or two images. For this I want to use an API but I don't know which one to use. A free or very inexpensive API if possible.
Do you know of a good API to do this?

The search for the car will be done via a basic search bar

In case this could be useful I would specify that the project will be done in Symfony php. In clean architecture because I'm trying to get started with that.

Thank you